# ActiveMQ Listener in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, activemq-classic

I have to write a Listener for ActiveMQ in python.

Is there any python package which could be used to write the listener.
Also what is with Stomp/Openwire protocol. When i start activemq, i see three urls with protocol namely tcp, ssl, stomp.

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT!**: Another question I have is suppose we start the broker with stomp as well as openwire protocol. Lets say the broker Url is now tcp://localhost:61616 and stomp://localhost:61613. So now the broker is listening on two different ports. My question is if a producer publishes a message on tcp port will that message could be consumed by a subscriber on stomp port? Also what If two subscribers on tcp and stomp respectively are waiting on the same queue, will they both receive the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python you can use something like [stomppy](http://code.google.com/p/stomppy/) which will let you inter-operate with any broker that is STOMP aware.  ActiveMQ uses its own openwire protocol natively but can also talk STOMP and MQTT.  You need to add a STOMP TransportConnector, see the [STOMP page](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) at ActiveMQ.

Comment: though there is no more development on pyactivemq, is the latest version (0.1.0) stable. I installed pyactivemq but i am getting pyactivemq.CMSException: OpenWireFormatNegotiator::requestWire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format. Also the producer is written in Java and I just want to write a consumer. Also my problem is the system admin has only started the openwire protocol and not the stomp protocol as such I had to abandon STOMP.py although I thought about using it earlier. @TimBish, I guess you are the author of pyactivemq, can you held me figure out the error.

Comment: I'm not the author of pyActiveMQ, the original author has no more interest in the project so its not maintained and doesn't support the latest versions of ActiveMQ-CPP upon which it is built.  I don't really know anymore what the last version was it supported.  You'd be better off looking at a Stomp python client that's been maintained.

Comment: I have your comments all over in pyactivemq discussion threads. Anyways, using Stomp python is my last option as I will have to talk to system admin to start that protocol. Also two consumers one queue, both receive copy of each message...sounds wrong or it is?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am using STOMP python for listening to a ActiveMQ Broker. PyActiveMq is to unstable to be used as it is no more maintained.

Comment: could you share your code? I want to listen to a topic online using python. so should I build an active durable subscriber ? and how